# 'lc_time_names' can't be set to the value of 'de_DE'

Tags: mariadb, locales, mariadb-10.8

Works:

```sql
SET lc_time_names='en_US';
```

Fails with "Variable 'lc_time_names' can't be set to the value of 'de_DE'":

```sql
SET lc_time_names='de_DE';
```

This seemed simple to me. I guess, I have to install that locale but no search for "mariadb install locale" or "mariadb add locale" returned anything helpful. So I thought the available locales might be tied to the OS. I am using macOS, so `locale -a` lists me locales galore, "de_DE" is among them.

I ran the exact same database with that locale without problems but had to update macOS and reinstall php via `brew install php@8.0`. This updated more than just php. Afterwards, the error appeared.

Comment: It's not tied to the OS. See [locales plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/locales-plugin/) to expose information.

Comment: what mariadb version?

Comment: @danblack: MariaDB 10.8.3. It wasn't available as a tag. I, too, am interested in the locale listing by MariaDB, but the installation fails with "Can't open shared library 'locales.so' (errno: 8, API version for INFORMATION SCHEMA plugin LOCALES not supported by this version of the server)". However, I am more concerned about getting that locale to work. The locale plugin could only show me a binary option: The locale exists or it doesn't exist. Do you have any idea, what I could in any of those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to produce this. When the `SET lc_time_names='de_DE';` was executed I got the following error immediately in the server log:

```
 2023-02-10  9:30:48 3 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/local/mysql/share/errmsg.sys'
```

I found it odd how it affected some locale names and not others.

I corrected this by adding the configuration option `lc-messages-dir=PATH_TO_ERRMSG.SYS/share/english`. I'm not totally sure where brew installs it but it might be under `/usr/local`.

The ABI error with `locales.so` might indicate there's some remains of a MySQL or other MariaDB server there, which could explain the issue with `lc-message-dir`.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into that problem and providing a helpful answer! It solved my issue. The correct setting is in my case: `lc_messages_dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb/share/mysql/`. I had to add that variable to my.cnf, it wasn't even there. What I learned: The immediate error message in the client can be a bit misleading. I should have looked into the error log file. When I try to set an unknown locale like 'test' now, it gives me a proper message: "Unknown locale: 'test'".
Btw, in most cases lc_messages_dir should not contain the language name.

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#lc_messages_dir for the behaviour of that setting.